# How to estimate computation time by the number of loops

Tags: r, algorithm

If I know how many loops an algorithm in R will need to complete the task, how could I estimate the computational time?

Here an example:

```
length(vector_a); # 30000
length(vector_b); # 100000

for (i in vector_a) {
   for (j in vector_b) {
print("This is one loop")
   }
}
```

Then I should have 30,000 * 100,000 = 3,000,000,000 loops before completing the job. Now if I have a 2.6Ghz computer with 4GB of memory how long should take? How do you do the math?

Comment: It will greatly depend on what you are doing inside your loop (and how you are doing it). --printing is slow!

Comment: As another example of (bad) code that is iterative and gets much slower as `i` increases, consider this: `x <- c(); for(i in 1:100000) x <- c(x, i)`. It's a very common malpractice in R!

Comment: 3e9 iterations, each costing, say, 1ms, total 34.7 days of computation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the task is more-or-less the same on the last loop as it is in the first (as it is in your exmaple), you can get a **very** rough estimate by measuring the time it takes to complete some subset of your tasks, and dividing by the fraction of the total loops that you executed. For instance,

```
vector_a <- 1:10; # 30000
vector_b <- 1:10;

system.time(
  Rprof({
    for (i in vector_a) {
      for (j in vector_b) {
        print("This is one loop")
      }
    }
  })
  )
```

On my machine this yields

```
  user  system elapsed 
 0.008   0.002   0.008
```

If we go with the `elapsed` time here, which is the most conservative, we get `0.008 / ((10*10)/(30000*100000)) = 240000` seconds.

However, this is a poor approximation in the best case, and will fail badly if the computation is iterative and becomes more computationally expensive on each loop, as for instance in

```
for(i in 1:100) {
  factorial(i)
}
```